# Changes in SVD decomposition when $A$ changes to $4A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

If  A  changes to $4A$, what is the change in SVD?

$$A^tA=(U \Sigma V)^t(U \Sigma V)$$

So, if we change $A$ to 4A,

$$(4A^t)(4A)=16(A^tA)=16(U \Sigma V)^t(U \Sigma V)$$

It seems like that SVD decomposition is multiplied by 16, but I am not sure...

Alsom

What is the SVD for $A^T$ and $A^{-1}$?

Comment: This is one of several contexts in which one finds out the difference between the symbols produced by \sum and \Sigma: $\displaystyle U\sum V$ looks different from $\displaystyle U\Sigma V$.  I changed the former to the latter.  (There are also other differences that don't appear in this instance.) $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't able to find out the lower case of sum

Comment: There is no lower case of "sum".  There is the capital $\Sigma$ and there is the lower-case $\sigma$ (coded respectively as \Sigma and \sigma).  In a displayed, as opposed to inline, setting, one sees $$ \sum_{j=1}^{30} $$ by using \sum, whereas with \Sigma one sees $$ \Sigma_{j=1}^{30}, $$ and the latter form is incorrect usage. In an inline setting \sum yields this: $\sum_{j=1}^{30}$, with the subscript and superscript to the right. At any rate the capital \Sigma is not lower case, and \sum has no lower case. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

When $A=U \Sigma V^T$, $4A=U (4 \Sigma) V^T$. Now $U$ and $V$ are still unitary and $4 \Sigma$ is still diagonal with nonnegative entries, so this is indeed the SVD of $4A$. Note that this would not work as written with $-A$, since $-\Sigma$ doesn't have nonnegative entries.

You seem to have confused the SVD of $A$ with the eigendecompositions of $A^T A$ and $A A^T$. These are related (in the sense that you can easily compute one from the other) but not the same.

Comment: Hi Thank you. Then, for A^t, wouldn't it naturally follow that A^t=VEU^t ? (E for sigma) as A is defined?

Comment: @dlalz That's correct, assuming $A$ is square. If not then you need to transpose $\Sigma$.

Comment: Even if A is not square, isn't it always true that Σ would be square?, since the way we find Σ is that we consider eigenvalues of A^tA or AA^t, which is always square.

Comment: @dlalz With the full SVD, no. If $A$ is $m \times n$ then $U$ is $m \times m$, $\Sigma$ is $m \times n$, and $V$ is $n \times n$. This ensures that $U^T U = I_m$ and $V^T V = I_n$ (i.e. they are "really" unitary).

Comment: Thanks, I have a last question. To find A inverse, do we have to assume that SVD is in reduced form? otherwise there would be no inverse of Σ as long as one of the rows is 0

Comment: @jessie First, the question of the inverse only makes sense if $A$ is square. For a full SVD of a square matrix, $\Sigma$ is also always square and it is invertible if and only if if $A$ is invertible. For a reduced SVD of a square matrix, $\Sigma$ is always square and invertible, but $U$ and $V$ are rectangular if $A$ is not invertible. In particular, $U^T U$ will still be $I_r$ (where $r$ is the rank of $A$) but $U U^T$ will not be $I_n$ (where $A$ is $n \times n$). Similarly $V^T V$ will be $I_r$ but $V V^T$ will not be $I_n$.

Comment: @jessie This inconvenience is part of why the full SVD is convenient for theoretical work even though it is somewhat bad for numerical work.